# How can I count white spaces using substr_count() in PHP

Tags: php

how can I count the number of white spaces in a file using PHP?

I have tried the substr function but it isn't working.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be to remove all other characters and count what's left. You could do this with something like the following:

```
$count_var = preg_replace('[^\s]', '', $string);
$count = strlen($count_var);
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace any non-whitespace with nothing, count the result:

```
echo strlen(preg_replace('/\S/', '', $text));
```

This works for *any* whitespace, including tabs the like.
`substr_count` should work fine though for regular spaces:

```
echo substr_count($text, ' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

int **substr_count** ( string *$haystack* , string *$needle* [, int *$offset = 0* [, int *$length* ]] )
http://br3.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

```
<?php
$text = 'This is a test';

echo substr_count($text, ' '); // 3
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$test = "sadlk asd sad sda";
$whitespaces = substr_count($test," ");
```

[substr_count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)